# Start arrow from a point at a certain distance from a node

Tags: nodes

I want to do something like this:
[image]

Please tell me how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta,positioning} 
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
        >=Latex,
        very thick,
        block/.style= {draw, rectangle, text width=2cm,minimum height=1cm,align=center},
        ]
        \node [block] (start1) {Start1};
        \node [block, below right = 1cm and 2cm of start1.east] (end1) {End1};
        \node [block, below= 2cm  of start1] (start2) {Start2};

        \path [draw, ->] ($(start1.south)+(-0.5,0)$) --  ($(start2.north)+(-0.5,0)$);
        \path [draw, ->] ($(start1.south)+(0.5,0)$) |- ($(end1.west)+(0,0.2)$);
        \path [draw, ->] ($(end1.west)+(0,-0.2)$) -| ($(start2.north)+(0.5,0)$);
\end{tikzpicture} \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
A small variation of the nice @jsbibra answer (+1), with slightly shorter code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[> = Latex,
node distance = 2mm and 8mm,
box/.style = {draw, thick, minimum height=1cm, text width=2cm, align=center},
every path/.style = {draw, -Stealth, semithick}
                        ]
\node [box] (start1)    {Start1};
\node [box, below right=of start1]  (start2)    {Start2};
\node [box, below  left=of start2]  (end1)      {End1};
%
\draw   (start1.240) -- (end1.120);
\draw   (start1.300) |- (start2.170);
\draw   (start2.190)  -| (end1.60);
    \end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the connectors should be arrows not lines

Comment: @jsbibra, you are right.  Coorected now.

Comment: Thanks so much both of you!!